# How would one install a side by side installation of Python 2.x, and Python 3.x

Tags: python

I think the title says it all.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/487860/shifting-between-alternate-versions-of-python-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python 3 is available from the repositories and can be installed side by side with Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python
```

You can use the `-V` switch to find out the minor version numbers:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.1.2

$ python -V
python 2.6.6
```

Answer (score 0):

comment: please note that python 2 and 3 will use different output channels for their prints whilst the returned code will be zero in case of success.

```
command=python2 --version
rc=0
stderr=Python 2.7.12
```

.

```
command=python3 --version
rc=0
stdout=Python 3.5.2
```